# Which active sects/subsects today have names that are not in Sanskrit?

Tags: sanskrit, name, sects

the major sect names like Saiva,Vaishnava etc. are in sanskrit.  Some sects have names that end in "Samaj" which is in Hindi.

What are the major sects/subsects active today whose names are not in Sanskrit?

Comment: Arya Samaj (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arya_Samaj) is a reform movement not a sect (Sampradaya). An organization founded by a human being is not a sect.

Comment: @Rickross can you please elaborate more on this statement...'An organization founded by a human being is not a sect'..Like..Umm.. I have seen some Iskcon people claiming that they are vaishnava but Iskcon was founded by Srila Prabhupada(Human) , I personally don't think that they are a 'sect'.

Comment: ISKCON is an organization not a sect. The sect they are part of is Gaudiya Vaishnavism. A sect always starts with God. @LSSJBroly

Comment: Sorry! I just got to know , I was not able to interpret your statement correctly. Actually I confused it with something else. ^_^; @Rickross

Comment: Sanskrit is the language of the gods, as per tradition. So any a traditional /orthodox sect (sampradaya) must have a Sanskrit name generally, tracing lineage to a Divinity. Even worship must be in Sanskrit.

Answer (score 1):

In South India - there are two sect names - Iyer and Iyengar that are in Tamil.  They have Sanskrit equivalents - Smarta ans Srivaishnava.

the iyengar subsects - vadakalai and tenkalai are purely in Tamil.

BAPS Bochasanwasi Akshar Purushottam Swaminarayan Sanstha also is not in pure Sanskrit.